# Remove a term which includes a defined variable from an equation

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, replacement, symbolic, filtering

Is it possible to remove a term which includes a defined variable from an equation?

my equation is something like:

```
qq := {a*b^2*FIinAlpha31''''[t] + 2*c*d*e*cos (FIinAlpha32[t])}
```

and I want to remove the term which includes `FIinAlpha31''''[t]`, so the result whould be

```
+2*c*d*e*cos (FIinAlpha32[t])
```

I tried `deleteWith` and `DeleteCases`, but none of them gave the result I'm after.

I appreciate any help.

I can derive the term which includes `FIinAlpha31''''[t]` with `Coefficient` if it's needed

Answer (score 4):

Just:

```
qq /. FIinAlpha31''''[t] -> 0
```

Comment: this does not work, when sending equations from matlab, to remove in mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

```
qq := {a*b^2*FIinAlpha31''''[t] + 2*c*d*e*cos (FIinAlpha32[t])}

qq /. Derivative[_][_][_] -> 0

(* {3/2 c cos d FIinAlpha32[t]} *)
```

Or

```
Cases[qq, _?(FreeQ[#, Derivative] &), {2}]

(* {3/2 c cos d FIinAlpha32[t]} *)
```

Or

```
DeleteCases[qq, _?(! FreeQ[#, Derivative] &), {2}]

(* {3/2 c cos d FIinAlpha32[t]} *)
```

Comment: I have other derivatives in my equation too, this was the simplest example I have. So I cannot specify if there is derivative remove that.

Comment: You can replace one or more blanks with values to make it as specific as necessary.